# In postman tests, how can I find if a value is set where another value is equal to something?

Tags: postman

**Example**:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "value": 1000,
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "value": 500,
    },
]
```

I want to basically say check that value is 1000 where id = 1.

**The code:**

```js
pm.test("Check value is correct", function () {
    const responseJson = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(responseJson.value = 1000);
    pm.expect(responseJson.id = 1);
});
```

Is that the correct way to do that test? Or is that going to check both is valid?

Answer (score 1):

`responseJson` is an array, so it is not going to work, because you are not accessing any array element. Always try your code first. There are other problems, e.g. `pm.expect(responseJson.value = 1000);` is not gonna work, you have to chain the checks, this syntax is incorrect.

You can filter based on id and check the value then:

```js
pm.test("Check value is correct", function () {
    const responseJson = pm.response.json();
    const [filteredObject] = responseJson.filter(el => el.id === 1);
    pm.expect(filteredObject.value).to.eql(1000);
});
```

I recommend reading [test examples in Postman docs](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/test-examples/).